# MVC show message on object tag has error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code to retrieve a pdf file and display in the view (it's a bootstrap modal partial view). Things are good except when the PDF is empty, or any error is being thrown, I only see an empty modal. Does anyone know if there's a way that I can post a short message like "sorry, error!" back to the view when there's error?

Also, it needs to be in the view, not a popup alert box.

**Partial View:**

```
<div class="modal-body" id="modal-content">
    <object data="@Url.Action( GeneratePDF, MyPDF)"></object>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
public FileStreamResult GeneratePDF()
{
    MemoryStream memStream = SomeService.GetPDFinStream();
    if ( memStream.Length <= 0 )
    {
       // I want to throw a simple error msg back, what to do?
    }
    else
    {
        return new FileStreamResult(memStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Redirect it to error controller and from there you can provide a button to the user to navigate to the correct page. By this way, you can also log the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TempData` to store error message and in the View place JavaScript so that if error message is not null, then show an alert

```
    if ( memStream.Length <= 0 )
    {
       // I want to throw a simple error msg back, what to do?
      TempData["CustomNullError"] = "sorry, error";
    }
```

**View Code**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var msg = '@TempData["CustomNullError"]';
            if (msg.length > 1) {
                alert(msg);//
                // or set error message in label/ span
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Alert message isn't popping... I think it might be because my partial view is inside a modal window. Anyway, If I want to show the message on the page instead. I tried this way but still not working, would you be able to help?

<div class="modal-body" id="general-modal-content">
 <div id="modal-Error">Error Message</div>
 <div id="modal-PDF">
      <object id="objectPDF" data="@Url.Action( Constants.Actions.GenerateBill, Constants.Controllers.BillPresentment )" width="100%" height="600"></object>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#modal-Error').hide();
  var msg = '@TempData["CustomNullError"]';
  if (msg.length > 1) {
   alert(msg);
   $('#modal-PDF').hide();
   $('#modal-Error').show();
  }
        });
</script>

Comment: The JavaScript should be placed in main View bottom where the Partial View is rendered.